# default java method with a switch method

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to locate a (built-in) java method that uses the switch statement.

To clarify my question, I am not asking how to use a Java switch statement. 
I realize I can create my own method and put switch statement in it.

I am looking for a method within Java that has such statement incorporated in its code.

To clarify my question even further, I would like to find a method within the Java API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/dofucs/api/ that uses the switch statement.

Thank you!

Comment: so extract the src.zip and grep for it.

Comment: You're looking for *usage* of a switch statement in the Java API? And grepping for it in the library source doesn't help? Also, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of all .java files in the source that mention "switch" (most of them appear to be using the switch statement, although a few seem to be merely discussing it in comments).

http://pastebin.com/grBqEjBE

But to answer the original question: Among the many examples, here's one from `JLabel.java`:

```
    public String getAtIndex(int part, int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= getCharCount()) {
            return null;
        }
        switch (part) {
        case AccessibleText.CHARACTER:
            try {
                return getText(index, 1);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                return null;
            }
        case AccessibleText.WORD:
            try {
                String s = getText(0, getCharCount());
                BreakIterator words = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(getLocale());
                words.setText(s);
                int end = words.following(index);
                return s.substring(words.previous(), end);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                return null;
            }
        case AccessibleText.SENTENCE:
            try {
                String s = getText(0, getCharCount());
                BreakIterator sentence =
                    BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(getLocale());
                sentence.setText(s);
                int end = sentence.following(index);
                return s.substring(sentence.previous(), end);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                return null;
            }
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Which is indeed [available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.AccessibleJLabel.html#getAtIndex%28int,%20int%29) in the Java API.